# here is my code for my login system. Any advice for improving it and ending the 'if' loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

## I have created a 'for' loop in order for the user to re-enter his/her username and password. Hovever, It does not yet work because the loop is infinite. Please help.

```
print('welcome to the general knowledge quiz')

User = input('please create a Username: ')
password = input('ok, please create a password: ')
store_User =[]
store_password =[]
if User in store_User:
 store_User.append.txt(User)
 store_password.append.txt(password)

while 1 == 1:
    Userguess=""
    passwordguess=""
    key=""

    open("Users","w+")
    ("Users","a")

    while (Userguess != User) or (passwordguess != password):
        Userguess = input('User: ')
        passwordguess = input('password:')
```

Comment: `while 1 == 1:` is infinite and you are not breaking it `break`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the outside while loop, just delete the `while 1 == 1` and unindent the rest of the code below it and it will work.

Comment: That is far from the only issue with this code... it will not work as suggested.

Comment: @TemporalWolf The code will work with the suggestions I offered in python3, which this code looks to be.  It will prevent the *specific* problem the OP asked about, which is the infinite loop.